# PHP MySQL stored procedure incomplete results

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a database that includes an Items table, in which each Item has a parent location (e.g., "Check book" in "Drawer A" in "File Cabinet" in "Office" in "House"). I created a stored procedure to extract a location hierarchy from the Items table and store it in a separate table, Location Chain. This is the stored procedure code:

```
drop procedure if exists GetLocationChain;
delimiter //
create procedure GetLocationChain(in piItemId INT UNSIGNED)
begin
  set @liItemID := piItemId;
  truncate table LocationChain;
  while @liItemID > 0 do
    insert into LocationChain(ItemId, Item, Description, ParentLocId, Notes)
      select ItemId, Item, Description, ParentLocId, Notes
      from Items
      where ItemId = @liItemID;

    select @liItemID := ParentLocId from Items where ItemId = @liItemID;
    end while;

  end//

delimiter ;
```

I can run this from the MySQL command line and it works as expected, with as many records in the chain as there should be. In the above example that would be five records: (1) "Check book", (2) "Drawer A", (3) "File Cabinet", (4) "Office", (5) "House".

I have a PHP file that calls my stored MySQL procedure using the following code:

```
$lsSQL = 'call GetLocationChain(' . $lnSeldItemId . ');';
if(!$result = $db->query($lsSQL)){
  die('There was an error running the query [' . $lsSQL.']: error [' . $db->error . ']');
  }
$db->close();
```

When I run this, the LocationChain table never has more than two records, even if the location chain is longer than that. I get no more than two records whether I query the LocationChain table from within the PHP file or directly from the MySQL command line.

Even though my called procedure does not return a result, I tried inserting code into my PHP code to extract it:

```
$lsSQL = 'call GetLocationChain(' . $lnSeldItemId . ');';
if(!$result = $db->query($lsSQL)){
  die('There was an error running the query [' . $lsSQL.']: error [' . $db->error . ']');
  }
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $array0[] = $row;
  }
$db->close();
```

Adding the fetch row code made no difference.

Anyone have any suggestions for where to look for the cause of the problem?

Comment: Can an item have multiple children? Also, you contradict yourself. First, you wrote that the sp works from command line client, then you wrote it only produced 2 items out of the list in the cli. Which is true?

Comment: Have you tried to just make it a query in php to try if there is anything wrong? Just call a query in php instead of a stored procedure for trouble shooting.

Comment: Each item has exactly one parent location, and that's the direction that the while loop runs, from child to parent to parent to parent etc. One parent location can have multiple child items, but I'm not sure that's relevant. If I call the stored procedure from the MySQL command line, it works correctly, producing more than 2 records where appropriate. It only fails when I call the stored procedure using PHP code. I guess I could try pushing the loop logic into the PHP, but I would like to avoid rewriting it if at all possible.